# How, or is it possible in TeamCity to define an environment variable that can be used in the VCS root to checkout specific tags and build these?

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have a TeamCity project setup that currently looks at the **trunk** of my svn project, checks that out, builds it, deploys it to a server and then runs some tests on that. I set this up so there would be 1 click deployment of services, however it can only be used from the trunk.

I would like to setup the TeamCity project so that when given a specific svn tag (in an environment variable for example) it checks out that tag rather than the trunk and builds, deploys and tests this tag. Is it possible to change the VCS root to point to the tag I define? If not is there another way in which I can do this?

I'm using TeamCity version 4.5.4

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This link offers a glimmer of hope - http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Build+Configuration+Template although it is refering to TeamCity 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is not possible in 4.x or below. Well there is a hack around you could perform in your build scripts but that is ugly!!

This is only truly possibly in 5.x and >. You would have to use something called "templates".

Here is a [tutorial](http://skepticalhumorist.blogspot.com/2010/02/release-builds-with-teamcity-selecting.html) on how to set these up which should save you all the time I spent Googling around to try find an answer to this.

Good luck!